# transfer a file to remote dir only if doesn't exist without replacing

Tags: shell-script, ssh, rsync, scp, file-transfer

I'm using CentOS linux.

In one line cmd, that returns 0 if success, non-0 if failure, I need:

> 1. Transfer a file to a remote server.
> 2. Don't transfer the file if filename exists in remote server (return non-0)

I thought about using `rsync`, but it returns 0 if the filename exists.
`scp` replaces the existing file, so it doesn't help me either.

**A twist**: The user that performs this command is **not** root, the files are owned by this user. The destination is owned by same user. There is an `ssh` trust for root. But not for this user. Can't be prompted for password, because this command is part of an automatic script. Preliminary configuration steps are possible. I can add them as a one time configuration. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way that doesn't preserve metadata:

```
ssh server.example.com 'set -C; cat >/path/to/remote/file' </path/to/local/file
```

You can do it with rsync with the right options. The return code will be 0 if the file exists, but you can find out from the verbose output instead.

```
changes=$(rsync -a --ignore-existing --itemize-changes \
                /path/to/local/file server.example.com:/path/to/remote/file)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo >&2 "Some error occured"
  return 2
elif [ -n "$changes" ]; then
  echo "The file was copied"
  return 0
else
  echo "The file already existed"
  return 1
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if the file exists on the remote host first:

```
if ! ssh remotehost [ -f incoming/DB1026910.sql ]; then
    scp DB1026910.sql remotehost:incoming/
fi
```

Comment: What if the file is created in the meantime? Perhaps even more crucially, what if there is _some other error_ in the first connection?

Comment: A one-liner would be something like "ssh remotehost test ! -f /tmp/filename && scp /tmp/filename remotehost:/tmp/". It requires 2 sessions, which i would like to avoid, and it fails under the listed above reasons